# Regex matching in OData Filter query

Tags: java, regex

I have to match patterns from a main string using regex in java 8

This is the pattern I have so far.

```
Email.*?(:parameter[0-9]+[^,])
```

It works on line 1 and line 2 below but fails on line 3 by matching just this `Email IN (:parameter10`

```
Note: I am fine with the closing bracket at the end being matched or not, I can work either way

// should match "Email = :parameter1)"
String line1 = "(Email = :parameter1)"; 

// should match "Email IN (:parameter1,:parameter2)"
String line2 = "(Email IN (:parameter1,:parameter2) AND (FirstName = :parameter3))"; 


// should match "Email IN (:parameter10,:parameter11)"
String line3 = "(Email IN (:parameter10,:parameter11) AND (FirstName = :parameter13))";
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `Email.*?(:parameter[0-9]+)(?![0-9,])` or `Email.*?(:parameter[0-9]+)(?![\d,])\)?`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks! this works. Could you explain it please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
Email.*?(:parameter[0-9]+)(?![0-9,])\)?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ht9Ing/1). *Details*:

- `Email` - a fixed string
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(:parameter[0-9]+)` - Group 1: a `:` char, then `parameter` word and then one or more digits
- `(?![0-9,])` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a digit or a comma immediately to the right of the current location
- `\)?`  - an optional `)` char.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your input, technically this is sufficient:

```
Email[^)]*\)
```

It takes everything for Email up to the last ) inclusive.

If you want more validation on the parameterX then this is more specific

```
Email.*?((:parameter\d+,?)+)\)
```

It takes Email then anything until first parameter then optional other parameter and again ends by the )